# The C programming language Second Edition practice 1-9

Tags: c

The specific question is this: the user enters the text, for example, if the user enters

```
hello (spaces) (spaces) world
```

The output that the user gets is

```
hello (space) world.
```

The following is my code, the adjustment of the number of spaces can be achieved, I am a bit confused because my output will *eat the first letter*. I want to know why this will happen.

**The code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int characters = 0;
    while ((characters = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (characters != ' ') {
            putchar(characters);
        }

        if (characters == ' ') {
            while ((characters = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(' ');
        }

    }
}
```

**The output:**

```
Hello  world  world  world
Hello orld orld orld
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the output in the question (copy-and-pasted if possible) as text, formatted as code (use the **{}** button). Images of text are discouraged.

Comment: Please post console output as code formatted text, not images

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time I use stackoverflow, I will pay attention to it next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
    if (characters == ' '){
        while ((characters = getchar()) == ' ');
        putchar(' ');
    }
```

This code will keep eating characters until it eats a non-space. But you don't want to eat any non-spaces. A simple fix:

```
    if (characters == ' '){
        while ((characters = getchar()) == ' ');
        putchar(' ');
        putchar(characters);
    }
```

Now you eat characters until you eat a non-space, then you output one space, then you output the non-space character you ate.

Comment: You also need to check for EOF here. Probably don't want to print that.

Comment: May also want an `else break;` after that check on `EOF` to prevent calling `getchar()` again on a stream with `EOF`.